# Transforming numbers into fake randoms that are actually deterministic

Tags: random

How can I convert a number into a seemingly random number in a process that is actually *deterministic*?

For example I'd like to transform: `123456` into `51`.
Or `28`. Doesn't matter as long as it's a number between 1 - 1000.

The value should be significantly different for similar inputs.
Transforming `123456` should give a very different number from transforming
`123457`. I recall reading about these processes when I was younger in some paper about cryptography but i can't recall their name. <strike>"Cascading functions?" "Waterfall functions?" I don't remember but anyway..</strike> I was talking about the [avalanche effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect).

The process should be deterministic. It should give the same output for input
`123456` every time I run it.

### Context:

I'm creating a tool that scours logfiles across geographical servers and helps us view the errors and their frequency so we can understand cause-and-effect. Each error occurrence appears at a point on a time plot.

The x-axis has the time of the error.
The y-axis; I don't need to use. But I don't want all the errors that happened at a similar time to appear on the same y-point on my plot.

So what I'm doing is the following:

I select a random number for that log's y-axis value. But when I run my tool again, that point appears on a different position because of the random number. It's no real problem for the investigative purposes we use it for but it looks a bit wonky, every time I run the tool I don't want the point to jump around.

[image: Image of the tool]

So instead of picking a random number, I've thought of chopping the log id (given as i.e '94827717') into a 1-10 decimal, like so:

```
  // this abomination actually works but its "randomness" probably 
  // depends on the number of concurrent users using the log service. 
  // I suspect `id` is an autoincrement value
  hashLogIdToNumber: id => {
    const wholeNumber = id.charAt(len - 3)
    const firstDecimal = id.charAt(len - 2)
    const secondDecimal = id.charAt(len - 1)

    return parseFloat(`${wholeNumber}.${firstDecimal}${secondDecimal}`)
  }
```

I use the last parts of the log id because they are the ones with the most variation. I suspect that `log.id` is an autoincremented value. I don't have control over it, it's given by the log service provider.

Comment: Sounds like you are talking about "hashing", and "hash functions".

Comment: Correction: I was talking about the [avalanche effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect), not "waterfall functions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a random number generator with the input number as the seed.

Comment: Dang, I knew I was being silly. Thanks.